# Sorting mail in Thunderbird by both unread status and by date

Tags: thunderbird, sorting, unread-mail

Is there any way to make Thunderbird sort mail so that unread mail is always at the top *and* the e-mails are sorted by date in descending order persistently? Maybe an add-on that someone can recommend?

I can get the desired sort order by first clicking the "Date" header to order by date, then click it again to get descending order, then click the "Read" header to order by unread status, then click it again to get descending order. After I restart Thunderbird, while the unread messages are still on top, the date order has reverted to ascending.

This annoys me no end as it causes a major disconnect between the mail that has just arrived (or that I've intentionally left [or market] unread) and the other recent mail as well as messages I've only just read.

I've only been trying Thunderbird again for a day or after trying it years ago and disliking it. The program has improved tremendously and I would consider switching permanently, though the sorting order is a deal-breaker for me.

Comment: A possible work-around would be to enable the quickfilter "unread"  and then sort by date.

Comment: Doesn't do exactly what I want, but it does make it easier to see the unread messages. I wasn't previously aware of the option.

Answer (score 5):

Click the settings button while looking at your inbox (the 3 hatch marks upper right on your inbox view)  point to "view" then "sort by" choose "read".  If necessary go in again and choose sort order "Descending"  It will sort unread to the top, by date, and then read by date, both descending.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please be aware you have posted an answer to a question that is very old. Although there is nothing wrong with doing so, just be aware you may not get a response.

Comment: Is it possible to additionally do this by the most recent message in a thread?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the settings box in the upper right of Thunderbird, go to view then sort by, make sure date is selected then in the below column select descending. Then the settings will save after closing. I'm not positive I understood the question but this is what I believe you want.