# How to move starred and unread messages to top without destroying the order by date (descending)?

Tags: email, thunderbird, sorting

I'm trying to order my messages in my thunderbird inboxes and have multiple issues.

I want to oder my mails like the following:

1. Importent (starred) messages should always stay on top.
2. Unread messages should stay below starred messages but always above read messages.
3. Read messages should always be below unread messages.
4. Any of the message blocks (important, unread, read) itself should be sorted by date descending (newest on top).

This is my only way to deal with a huge amount of messages I recieve. I'm new to thunderbird and adapted this behaviour from googles priority inbox.

Is there an easy way to achieve this sorting order? It's no issue at all to move important and unread messages to top, but if you try then to sort the messages by date aswell, then everything breaks.

And the second part of my question - if this is really possible to sort messages like described above, would there be any central setting to create a default sorting order like described above? I have multiple inboxes and I dont want to set up all ov them seperately.

Comment: Similar questions to: https://superuser.com/questions/454699/sorting-mail-in-thunderbird-by-both-unread-status-and-by-date & https://superuser.com/questions/852908/sort-mails-by-3-criteria-on-thunderbird