# Sort mails by 3 criteria on Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, sorting

I would like to sort my mails by 3 criteria, on this order :

1. Date (new mails up the list)
2. Read state (unread messages upper)
3. "Starred" (starred messages at the uppest)

But it seems that it is impossible to set more than 2 sorting criteria on Thunderbird, as soon as I try to add a third criteria, the first one that I've set is unset and my messages are always sorted by only 2 criteria.

Is there a way to use those 3 criteria ? (At the moment, I keep marking my important messages as "unread" each time I read them, which is not very practical).